# How to play url video using MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 10

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, ios10, xcode8

I got this response while hit the video url in MPMoviePlayerController:

> Playback failed with error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11853 "Playlist not received, See -[AVPlayerItem errorLog] for 2 events" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This data is damaged, incomplete, or incompatible., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Parse, NSDebugDescription=Playlist not received, See -[AVPlayerItem errorLog] for 2 events, NSUnderlyingError=0x175ac7c0 {Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-12884 "Playlist File not received" UserInfo={NSDescription=Playlist File not received}}}, not resolving (canResolve: YES, errorResolver: (null))

Comment: same issue here any help?

Comment: @vaibby the video URL hasn't received properly i think and this MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated from iOS 9 so that you can use AVPlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController.

Hope the following link will be usefull,

http://pinkstone.co.uk/tag/avplayerviewcontroller/